# Reading specific line from file

Tags: c, file, cstring

I am trying to read a specific line from a file using the code below.

```
char *getlinenum(char *filename, int lnum)
{
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    char *linebuf = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    if ((f = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL)
    {
        linebuf = (char *)malloc(2048);
        memset(linebuf, 0, 2048);
        for (i = 0; i < lnum; i++)
        {
            if (fscanf(f, "%[^\n]\n", linebuf) == EOF)
            {
                free(linebuf);
                fclose(f);
                printf("Returning NULL\n");
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        //tmp = strdup(linebuf);
        //free(linebuf);
        fclose(f);
        return linebuf;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

No matter what, this is always returning just an empty (zero) string. Any issues you see? Here is the test file:

```
/home/mainframe/b
/home/mainframe/dead.letter
/home/mainframe/.bash_history
/home/mainframe/a
/home/mainframe/f
/home/mainframe/e
/home/mainframe/c
/home/mainframe/g
/home/mainframe/.ssh/authorized_keys
/home/mainframe/.ssh
/home/mainframe/d
```

I don't really understand where it could end up with a zero string (not a nullpointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me (made no changes except removing uncesessary `tmp` variable)

One issue is if 0 is passed, the for loop never enters. Just change it to <= and/or add another if-statement at the beginning:

```
if( lnum <= 0 ) 
  return NULL;
```

to catch this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getlinenum(char *filename, int lnum)
{
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    char *linebuf = NULL;

    if( lnum <= 0 ) 
      return NULL;

    if ((f = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL)
    {
        linebuf = (char *)malloc(2048);
        memset(linebuf, 0, 2048);
        for (i = 0; i <= lnum; i++)
        {
            if (fscanf(f, "%[^\n]\n", linebuf) == EOF)
            {
                free(linebuf);
                fclose(f);
                printf("Returning NULL\n");
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        free(linebuf);
        fclose(f);
        return linebuf;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
   printf("%s\n", getlinenum("input.txt", 2));
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
/home/mainframe/dead.letter
```

Comment: works for me too. it could end up with a zero string if you pass a negative line number (or 0)

Comment: yeah, the issue ended up being a simple changing it to <= instead of just <... figured that out just a second ago. Will propose an edit.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly obvious problem not mentioned yet is that this code overflows the buffer if there is a line longer than 2048.

Another problem is that your `fscanf` string will skip blank lines (except for the first line of the file). I'm not sure if this was intentional. The `\n` matcher that you have on the end of the string means to *match all whitespace up till the next non-whitespace* even if that whitespace includes multiple newlines.

To fix that problem, you could remove that `\n` and just do a `fgetc()` after each `fscanf` to consume one newline.

To fix the buffer overflow I would recommend skipping up to the line you want without storing anything, and then using a `fgets` to get the line you are interested in. For example (here I also have factored out the cleanup code):

```
if (lnum < 1 || (f = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    return NULL;

char *buffer = NULL;

for ( ; lnum > 1; --lnum )
{
     if ( fscanf(f, "%*[^\n]") == EOF || fgetc(f) == EOF ) 
          break;
}

if ( lnum == 1 )
{
// or use the POSIX getline() function or similar, to avoid any size limitation and
// avoid the mucking around with fgets and \n
   buffer = calloc(1, 2048);

    if ( ! fgets(buffer, 2048, f) )
    { 
        free(buffer); 
        buffer = NULL;
    }
    else if ( buffer[0] && buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] == '\n' )
       buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = 0;
}

fclose(f);
return buffer;
```

Also, using `unsigned long long` for `line_num` would let you read more!

Comment: using a larger int type is sort of a bad idea, since there can only be so much the program does, but thank you for the fgetc